# How to find the integral of a recursive function

Tags: integration

How do I find the integral to a recursive function?  For example, given:

$a(s) = i + s j + s^2 k$

$s(t_0) = q $

$s(t + \epsilon) = s(t) + \epsilon a(s(t)) $

I want to find $s(t_1)$. I know I want something like the sum the $s(t+\epsilon)$ from $t_0 ... t_1$ as $\lim{\epsilon \to 0}$. I'm not quite sure how to express it as a proper summation, and then get the integral.

*$i,j,k,q$ are constants. $s$ is the function I'm trying to calculate. $\epsilon$ a infinitesimal, my attempt to show that $s$ is related to its previous value only in small increments.*

Comment: What are $i,j$ and $k$ in the definition of $a$? Also, what is $s$, is it a function or a variable? And what is $\epsilon$?

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully my intent with  $\epsilon$ is clearer.

Comment: Still slightly unclear. What exactly does the equation $s(t+\epsilon) = s(t) + \epsilon a(s(t))$ mean? Does it mean that this is true for small values of epsilon or that the limit of both sides as $\epsilon\to 0$ is equal?

Comment: It's true for small values of epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your equation into

$$s(t+\epsilon) = s(t) + \epsilon(i + j\cdot s(t) + k\cdot s^2(t))$$

Which can be rewritten into

$$\frac{s(t+\epsilon) - s(t)}{\epsilon} = i + j\cdot s(t) + k\cdot s^2(t)$$

Since this is true for all values of $\epsilon$, and assuming that $s$ is differentiable, that means that $s$ satisfies the differential equation (obtained by looking at the limit of the right-hand side expression as $\epsilon \to 0$

$$s'(t) = i + j\cdot s(t) + k\cdot s^2(t)$$

Do you have any experience with solving differential equations?

Comment: $s'$ is the $a$ in my question, no? My experience with differential equations is extremel limited (you may assume none).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Yes, $s'$ is indeed the $a$ in your question, in a way. More precisely, my answer shows you that the function $s$ satisfies the differential equation $s'(t) = a(s(t))$, where $s'$ is the derivative of $s$. You do know what a derivative is?

Comment: Yes, derivatives/integrals I'm fine with, I've just not solved a differential equation before, that is, I'm not quite sure what to do with this new information. I'm reading a bit now, I see this come up with speed/acceleration models which is basically what I'm doing.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Well, the differential equation that $s$ satisfies is a very special type of differential equation and can be solved by the method of "separating variables", described http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-odesep.pdf here.

Comment: Okay, so I just need to solve that equation to get a non-recursive form, and then I can use that do my integral.

Comment: Yes. You can actually calculate $s(t)$ with little problem.